# Django Admin changelist submit redirect

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to have django redirect to another page after submitting changes directly in the changelist view? (After specifying the `list_editable` fields)

Already tried with different methods `response_post_save_change`, `response_change` or `response_add` but none of them worked.

I suspect it may be within the `changelist_view`, not sure how to tackle it since it handles the form saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you'll need to override the `changelist_view` method in your admin class. That method returns a response-like object, and it's definitely possible to customize that value.

**Approach #1:** copy the entire `ModelAdmin.changelist_view` method into your own admin class, and then modify it to meet your needs. Probably the safest bet for your situation, even if you're only changing *one single line* of code in this method (which is [99 lines long at this moment](https://github.com/django/django/blob/653a7bd7b7c2f7c3ffe6b22be53da1472c491474/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1686)).

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @csrf_protect_m
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """
        The 'change list' admin view for this model.
        """
        ... omitting code that leads up to line 1756 (v3.2)  ...

        # Handle POSTed bulk-edit data.
        if request.method == 'POST' and cl.list_editable and '_save' in request.POST:
            ... omitting more code ...
            # This is it. Line 1785: change this to meet your needs
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

        ... omitting the rest of the code after this line ...
```

**Approach #2:** call it via `super()`, and then inspect/alter the results. This *could* potentially be unreliable (comments in the code), but here's what it would look like:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        request_full_path = request.get_full_path()
        response = super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
        # This is not a foolproof condition! In the changelist_view method, you can
        # see that it returns this redirect in the following scenarios:
        # - if action_failed (line ~1745 in django.contrib.admin.options, v3.2)
        # - successful bulk update of the changelist (this is the use case you're targeting)
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect) and response.location == request_full_path:
            # do something here, like return a redirect to a different URL
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_url_name'))

        return response
```

So I'm not sure how you would determine *which* of the two conditions caused it to return the `HttpResponseRedirect` object with the exact same parameters (same `status_code` and same `location`) - one is a submission failure, the other is submission success! But you might have some manner of doing so within your application, so I'll leave it at that.

I would choose approach #1 myself, although I definitely dislike the amount of code that has to be copied into your own codebase, and having to maintain it / think about it in the future. But that's probably the best way.